# Firefox add-on localStorage when browser is offline

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am creating a firefox extension called bookmarks management, where you can store the bookmarks.The problem is how can i store bookmarks during offline,and also how can i get those stored data and sync it to database once the browser is online. i was trying with **localstorage** object using javascript but i wont get it. can any body help me.

Thank you.